# why 'appName' is missing in mongodb currentOp for some command?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I applied appName for some of my projects but in currentOp it is missing for some queries. Mostly it is missing for count query.

```
{
        "desc" : "conn1786739",
        "threadId" : "140671499200256",
        "connectionId" : 1786739,
        "client" : "179.22.4.3:42354",
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : -1076773120,
        "secs_running" : 6,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(6928801),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "dbname.members",
        "query" : {
            "count" : "memebers",
            "query" : {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "condition1" : {
                                    "$gt" : 0
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "condition1" : 0
                            },

                        ]
                    }
                ],

            },
            "readConcern" : {

            }
        },
        "numYields" : 28,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r",
            "Collection" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
    }
```

I saw above result in currentOp, Even appName is set for query it is not appearing for certain queries.

Comment: Can you explain how you applied the app name? And please mention the queries that are missing/having the app name.

Comment: For more info https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-39114

Comment: The ticket didn't have connection string details. I tested with globalsign/mgo (also mentioned in the ticket), and it had appName info.  What did your PHP connection string look like?

Comment: it contains appname like: '/?appName=APPNAME' for some queries its working perfectly ..

Comment: @Rahul, which version of MongoDB PHPLIB are you using ?

Comment: mongodb - 3.4.17 and its not php specific, we are getting this issue with other lang as well like golang..etc .. globalsign/mgo - r2018.06.15

Answer (score 7):

This is new in version 4.0 and you have to include appName in the connection string.  Refer to the [online doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.appName).